# Is Mysql now() timestamp pickups from server time

Tags: mysql, unix, time

Does MySQL have its own timestamp or use the system timestamp, because I see a dependency in the timings:

- `date` command on unix server
- `select now()` command on MySQL server

These two show different times.

Comment: What is the difference between the two methods? Miliseconds? Hours? Days? [MySQL uses the system clock](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/114843).

Comment: As Kolink's answer indicates, we need more information to be able to conclusively answer this. Are they the same physical server?

Comment: @Jonathon, both are on same server.

Comment: Okay, but what about Mike's question? *How different* are the results?

Answer (score 3):

In normal, time zone mysql use system time zone.
You can check:
In mysql

```
show variables like '%time_zone%';
```

In linux command:

```
date
```

In some situations, server timezone vs mysql timezone different, please restart mysql.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, they're the same because I connect to `localhost`.

However, most shared hosting system use a separate machine for databases, and therefore the time may be different by a few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

`now()` in SQL is evaluated *at the database.* Not at the client.

Comment: Not sure how that relates to the question since he is talking about two server settings. Can you clarify?

Comment: His question talks about two *servers* as far as I can see: a 'Unix server' where he ran the `date` command, and a 'MySQL' server to which he submitted a `select now()` command, and he got the time at the SQL server as a result, which differed from the result of the `date` command at the Unix server.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I just did not understand your usage of "client" in this context. (I assume the person who down voted, did not either).

Comment: @Leigh The client is the one that submits the SQL.